# Shorter, better way to write a "query" involving virtual attributes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have this code in a model for an invoicing app. This virtual attribute `current_invoice` gets the only non-rescinded invoice associated with a contract. The code works but it seems really verbose. Can this be done in a prettier way?

```
  def current_invoice
    result = []
    invoices.each do |i|
      if i.current_status != "rescinded"
        result.push(i)
      else
        false
      end
    end
    if result.length > 1
      raise "Only one non-rescinded invoice association per contract"
    else
      result[0]
    end
  end
```

You might be wondering why not just do this...

```
invoices.where.not(current_status: "rescinded").first
```

...but current_status is a virtual attribute on invoice.

Comment: I know you said current_status is virtual, but is it initialised based on a value in the database, perhaps in another model and may be you could use that to create a query?

Comment: Related to the previous comment, if you could filter on the database level, it would be *much* faster than fetching all invoices and then filtering them in Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I would change:

1. The else false isn't being used for anything
2. Move "rescinded" logic to invoice instead of querying invoice and then comparing with a string.
3. use Array#reject to eliminate rescinded invoices

Add method to the Invoice class

```
class Invoice
  def rescinded?
    current_status == "rescinded"
  end
end
```

and then in your method

```
def current_invoice
  rescinded_invoices = invoices.reject &:rescinded?

  raise "Only one non-rescinded invoice association per contract" if rescinded_invoices.length == 1

  rescinded_invoices.first
end
```

EDIT for clarity:

```
def current_invoice
  non_rescinded_invoices = invoices.reject &:rescinded?

  raise "Only one non-rescinded invoice association per contract" if non_rescinded_invoices.length > 1

  non_rescinded_invoices.first
end
```

Comment: Plus one for the helpful alternative! But I'm trying to get invoices that were *not* rescinded so probably best to change the variable name. Also, would this be alright in the `current_invoice` method: `invoices.reject(&:rescinded?).first`? Without using a variable name at all if I were to ditch the exception.

Comment: yep.. without your exepction it could just be `invoices.detect(&:not_rescinded?)`

Answer (score 4):

Some notes:

- `result = []`: Try not to use generic names like `result`. Also, use plural names for collections.
- init empty array + each + conditional push = select/reject. More on [functional programming](https://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyFunctionalProgramming).
- `else false`. In an `each` block the value is ignored, so this does nothing.
- `result[0]`. People usually write `result.first`, but `[0]` is also ok.
- `if result.length > 1`. There is a serious conceptual problem here, validations should be enforced somewhere else (this is Rails, so using a validation callback).

I'd write:

```
def current_invoice
  non_rescinded_invoices = invoices.select { |i| i.current_status != "rescinded" }
  if non_rescinded_invoices.size > 1 # but this should be probably an AR validation
    raise("Only one non-rescinded invoice association per contract")
  else
    non_rescinded_invoices.first
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. I actually am checking that no invoices be created if one non-rescinded invoice exists as an ActiveRecord validation, but I thought it might be a good idea to double check it here and raise an exception. What do you think about that? Is it unnecessary duplication?

Comment: Yes, I think it's unnecessary, you need to trust your own code :) Personally I don't want a "read-only" method like this to raise an error regarding validations. Another matter would be if you wanted to do some asserts on the arguments of a method, some sanity checks here and there are ok.